# why do we use while 1: pass in thread in python

Tags: python

```
from thread import start_new_thread

num_threads = 0
def heron(a):
    global num_threads
    num_threads += 1

    # code has been left out, see above
    num_threads -= 1
    return new

start_new_thread(heron,(99,))
start_new_thread(heron,(999,))
start_new_thread(heron,(1733,))
start_new_thread(heron,(17334,))

while num_threads > 0:
    pass
```

This is simple code of thread i want to know in last line why do we use while loop

Comment: is the purpose to wait all threads?

Comment: It would seem as it is waiting for all threads to finish their work... but I'm no python expert.

Comment: The `while ... pass` loop is an empty loop that will do nothing until `num_thread` is equal to 0. If you write some code after your while loop, it will only be executed when all of the threads are executed. If you write some code right before the loop, the code will be executed at the same time as all the threads

Comment: Your title and last line of the question contradict each other. Are you about `while 1: pass` in the function - which you left out - or are you about `while num_threads > 0: pass`?

Comment: BTW: `return new` in the function run as a thread is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

The final while-loop waits for all of the threads to finish before the main thread exits.

It is expensive check (100% CPU for the spin-wait).  You can improve it in one of two ways:

```
 while num_threads > 0:
     time.sleep(0.1)
```

or by tracking all the threads in a list and joining them one-by-one:

```
for worker in worker_threads:
    worker.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

We want to keep process alive until all children finish the work. So we must keep executing something in main thread as long as any child is alive, hence the check for `num_threads` variable.

If it wasn't for this, all children threads would be killed ASAP main thread finished its work regardless of whether they actually finished their work, so waiting for them is mandatory to ensure everything is done.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Raymond Hettinger's answer: the parent process starts a number of threads, each of which does work.  We then wait for each to exit, so that we can collect and process their output. In this case each worker just outputs to the screen, so the parent just has to join() each task to make sure it ran and exited correctly.

Here's an alternate way to code the above.  It uses the higher-level library `threading` (vs `thread`), and only calls `join()` on threads besides the current one.  We also use `threading.enumerate()` instead of manually keeping track of worker threads -- easier.

code:

```
import threading

def heron(a):
    print '{}: a={}'.format(threading.current_thread(), a)

threading.Thread(target=heron, args=(99,)).start()
threading.Thread(target=heron, args=(999,)).start()
threading.Thread(target=heron, args=(1733,)).start()
threading.Thread(target=heron, args=(17334,)).start()

print
print '{} threads, joining'.format(threading.active_count())
for thread in threading.enumerate():
    print '- {} join'.format(thread)
    if thread == threading.current_thread():
        continue
    thread.join()
print 'done'
```

Example output:

```
python ./jointhread.py 
<Thread(Thread-1, started 140381408802560)>: a=99
<Thread(Thread-2, started 140381400082176)>: a=999
<Thread(Thread-3, started 140381400082176)>: a=1733

2 threads, joining
- <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140381429581632)> join
- <Thread(Thread-4, started 140381408802560)> join
<Thread(Thread-4, started 140381408802560)>: a=17334
done
```